# How to group Rules in drools and fire only particular Group rules?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I am building a rule Engine in which I want to group rules in such a way that for a particular fact drools will not check for all the rules instead it will check for the rule in a specific group.
 Is it possible to implement?

Comment: What's your concern? Performance? Or different logic for different facts?

Comment: To target rules of specific group, you can use agendaGroup or RuleflowGroup.

Comment: @EstebanAlivertiI have different facts but I don't know how to add it at runtime and how can I add rules after setting up the rule-engine.

Comment: @AbhijitI tried AgendaGroup but in the documentation, it is mentioned that Drools evaluates all the rules first then it executes the AgendaGroup rues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to implement, you have to implement a process with the rules you want to apply to the specific group, then you can implement a rule like this:

```
rule "start process if ..."
    when
        // Fact in specific group?
    then
        kcontext.getKieRuntime().startProcess("ProcessName");
end
```

I would recommend you to follow the official drools tutorial, specially the lesson 4: https://nheron.gitbooks.io/droolsonboarding/content/gettingStarted/lesson_4__ruleflow.html

They teach you how to do this step by step.

Comment: Is it compulsory to add a process to set up the rule-engine?

Comment: @Prog_G I'm not really sure, probably someone more experienced could solve that. Anyways this is a way to implement what you were after.